# PlaceHolderApi minecraft plugin Not working, how to fix?

Tags: plugins, minecraft, placeholder

I get no error messages while loading the plugin or reloading it
but every time I write something it will show it like this

%player_name%> something

and I don't know how to fix it (in the console it show it normal but not in ingame chat)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is off-topic and should be on Arqade

Answer (score 0):

In the coming time, if possible, do not post bugs/suggestions and other things about minecraft plugins here, but go to specific forums like Spigot or **READ** the instructions for the plugin carefully. https://github.com/PlaceholderAPI/PlaceholderAPI/wiki/Placeholders#player

Answer (score 0):

Try with /papi ecloud download player

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).